# Is it possible to capture image from Camera and pick from Gallery without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Android v6.0?

Tags: android, android-image, android-gallery, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-camera-intent

I am able to get image from camera without any permissions in API 22 by using /data/Android// as storage path (since Android allows this directory to be writable without explicitly asking for permission in API 19+).

Unfortunately, the same is not working in API 23. In fact, camera is returning `responseCode` as 0 (`RESULT_CANCELLED`)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
This version of code if working up to API 22

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File image_file = null;
try {
    image_file = File.createTempFile("image_file", ".jpg", getFilesDir());
    image_file.setWritable(true, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
image_file_uri = Uri.fromFile(image_file);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_file_uri);
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.image_intent_chooser_title));
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{cameraIntent});
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, it would include the code you are using to "get image from camera... by using /data/Android// as storage path".

Answer (score 0):

Is there any requirement that your application be used to capture the image? If not have a look at this link to use an existing camera application:

[Using Existing Camera Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

> When the [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method is executed, users see a camera application interface. After the user finishes taking a picture (or cancels the operation), the user interface returns to your application, and you must intercept the [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method to receive the result of the intent and continue your application execution. For information on how to receive the completed intent, see [Receiving camera intent result](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using the camera intent as answered by Cory Charlton.
[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/eluleci/09663616b15ecea81c39) should be very useful for you. It provide a helper class with two methods: selectImageFromGallery() and takePhotoWithCamera(). The first one allow picking picture from Gallery or device folders, and the second one to take a picture using the default camera. You can also send the picture to a crop intent to edit it and apply filters.